# What happens if you run Git init/commit within a virtualenv?

Tags: git, virtualenv

My question is fairly simple: do I have to deactivate from a virtual environment (virtualenv) to work with Git? Will there be any negative artifacts later if I decide to run things like `git commit` while still in a virtualenv?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of Git is not written in Python, so it should not be affected by what virtualenv you are in. In particular, `git commit` is written in C.

Comment: What is the community standard way to do this? Do you include your entire VirtualEnv in your Git repository somehow? If not, how do people who look at your Git repository know what was included in the VirtualEnv you developed in?

Answer (score 5):

No, you do not need to deactivate a virtualenv before using git. A virtualenv is an isolated Python environment which is basically just a folder where any necessary executables to use a Python package are stored. Git is not a Python package, so working with git will not affect your activated virtualenv.

A quick way to track Python requirements in git is using a `requirements.txt`. While your virtualenv is active, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which will create a file listing all the packages in your current environment and their respective versions. To then install those same requirements in a new virtualenv just run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.